# Using asp panels to hide/display blocks of html on the client works but I can't update textboxes in the block

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to use a single asp page to display a logon screen (2 boxes for user id and password). I placed these in a asp:panel on the client page. When the user logs on, the code behind sets the login panel's visible attribute to off and a separate data panel to visible. This works fine. When the user pushes a Logoff button on the second page, I reverse the process to display the log on page again. I also TRY to set the user name and password boxes to empty but the TextBox.Text = "" is ignored (performed in the code behind).

Is this a perverted use of panels or am I missing a setting?

The code looks like this:

In default.asp:

```
 <!––
 // display the login panel
 -->
 <asp:Panel ID="Panel_login" runat="server" visible="true" >
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_userID" runat="server" Font-Size="Small"                        Width="200px">
</asp:TextBox>  
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_password" TextMode="Password" runat="server" Font-Size="Small" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>  
<asp:Button ID="Button_login" runat="server" BorderStyle="Ridge" Font-Size="Small" OnClick="Button_login_Click" Text="Log In" /> 
</asp:Panel>
```

In the Code behind:

```
Panel_selectSession.Visible = false;
  Panel_login.Visible = true;
  TextBox_userID.Text = "";      
  TextBox_password.Text = "";
  Label4_msg.Text = "";
```

The 2 Textbox sets are ignored but the label set works because it is outside the panel.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "is ignored"? Does that line of code get hit? Have you run your code with the debugger attached? If you're new to ASP.NET, why are you starting with Web Forms?

Comment: Yes, I have stopped there in the debugger and the text change code is executed. However the text within the panel on the form does not change. Do you have a better suggestion for what I am trying to do? I am using Web forms because I found some examples which looked appropriate.

Comment: Perhaps you have some other code changing the text back. If you create a [MCVE] it should help narrow that down. And yes, I reccomend you learn ASP.NET MVC or a SPA framework (React/Redux, Angular, or Vue) along with ASP.NET Web API. Web Forms is a dying technology, for a good reason.